# What is the purpose of the `fa-fw` class?

Tags: font-awesome

Looking through the [examples on the fontawesome website](http://fontawesome.io/examples/), I notice a few make use of the class `fa-fw`. For example:

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
```

I have tried with and without it and I cannot see any notable difference.

What is the purpose of the `fa-fw` class?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Fixed Width Icons

I've opened the sample page in Chrome, opened inspector on the "Library"-Element of the [fw-sample](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#fixed-width) and removed the `fw`-class. This messes up the icon-alignment - and that is also mentioned as the purpose of fw: ensuring proper alignment of the icons :-)

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I can't believe I completely missed that "Fixed Width Icons" section in the exact same page I linked in my question! my bad...

Answer (score 5):

Icon size, some icons are bigger, if you use fa fa-fw, the size of the icon will be the same regardless of how big/small it should be.

Answer (score 1):

fa-fw class will align icons vertically center with fixed margin. so the size of each icon will not vary and they aligned below each other in the center.