# How to expand the size of a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a dropdown menu on my Wordpress website, but when I expand it on desktop resolutions, it doesn't display the font-awesome `fa fa` icons next to the words, and it doesn't show the whole menu.

How do I make it wider and longer, so all of my content is visible?

HTML code:

```
<div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right visible-sm visible-xs">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>

<div class="module-group right">
    <div class="module left">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul id="menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1496" class="menu-item 
                                               menu-item-type-post_type 
                                               menu-item-object-page 
                                               menu-item-home 
                                               current-menu-item 
                                               page_item 
                                               page-item-19 
                                               current_page_item
                                               menu-item-has-children 
                                               menu-item-1496 
                                               dropdown 
                                               active">
                    <a title="Home" href="https://adsler.co.uk/">Home </a>.
                    <span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data- toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-1499" class="fa fa-envelope menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1499">
                            <a title="Post an Ad" href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-place-ad/">Post an Ad</a>
                        </li>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your question so that the code is aligned. Aligned code is more readable and easier to debug, and it makes it more likely you'll receive help. I noticed that you didn't post the full HTML code - I expect anyone who tries to help you will need your full HTML and CSS to help.

Comment: Being able to look at a reproduceable sample even (here or via jsfilddle) would be even nicer.

Comment: Not sure how, but here is the page which you can view on desktop. https://adsler.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your site, I noticed the menu-items have the following HTML:

```
<li id="menu-item-1502" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1502">
<i class="fa fa-user"></i> <a title="Create Adsler Account" href="https://adsler.co.uk/create-account/">Create Adsler Account</a>
</li>
```

I don't know how much of that is yours and what came from WP (I don't use it, I'm afraid).
I edited it and this works:

```
<li id="menu-item-1502" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1502">
<a title="Create Adsler Account" href="https://adsler.co.uk/create-account/"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw">&nbsp;</i>Create Adsler Account</a>
</li>
```

Basically I used a separate `i`-tag for the FA-Icon and applied the [`fa-fw`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140132/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-fa-fw-class/41144876#41144876)-class, too. And I moved the icon inside the `a`-tag which avoids the linebreaks. If you have control over the menu so that you can adjust it in that way, it should work...

Comment: Thanks. Ill try it. But I'd have to do the same for each menu item?

Comment: Yeah, you‘d have to repeat this for all menu items.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Could you tell me where i find this html in WordPress? I looked in header.php and can see a kind of simplified menu, but not the menu which is there or shows up in html view-source.

Comment: As I said, I have no idea how WP does what it does. This is really a WP-Issue, I hope someone can jump in and help.