# Making font awesome icons the same width

Tags: font-awesome

I'm using a set of FontAwesome4 icons and I'm finding that they're not all the same width. This offsets the alignment on subsequent divs where different icons are used.

[image]

As you can see the `fa-file-text` icon is slightly narrower than the `fa-video-camera` icon. Is there any way to make them the same width? Or at least calculate a margin for the `fa-file-text` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a cue from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257505/css-fixed-width-in-a-span) I added a `float` and `width` to all the elements with icons. And this fixed it.

[image]

```
.entryicon{
  margin-left: 3px !important;
  margin-right: 3px !important;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You could have also used `fa-fw` ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140132/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-fa-fw-class/41144876#41144876 )